# Automate Drop Down Menu in Excel

Tags: ruby, excel, cucumber

Here am using Ruby/Cucumber framework to automate Excel. Here I need to automate Drop down menu for Excel. Am using win32ole and RAutomation gems for (ribbon,click the button etc.).But I need gem which can automate drop down menu  Does anyone knows of any ruby gem (or combination of gems)  or any method to automate this kind of functionality.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: RAutomation should support MS UI Automation ("ms_uia" adapter), so it can automate ribbon controls. But if you consider other languages [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.github.io/) also can do that. See [MS Paint automation example](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/mspaint.py). The core concept is described in [the docs](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: As far as I know RAutomation is not so tolerant to different Ruby versions, and tech support is not so friendly (my student reported a bug but it was closed without fixing).

Comment: There are not so many desktop GUI automation tools in the open source field. I believe all of them are listed [in this rating](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings) and only six of them support MS UI Automation and therefore can automate Excel GUI.

Comment: ToolbarWindow32 class having three buttons , i need click on second button , not able to click on it.In Excel , i got below info from Auto IT

Control <<<<
Class: ToolbarWindow32
Instance: 1
ClassnameNN: ToolbarWindow321
Name:
Advanced (Class): [CLASS:ToolbarWindow32; INSTANCE:1]
ID:
Text:
Position: 304, 79
Size: 615, 28
ControlClick Coords: 45, 14
Style: 0x52001101
ExStyle: 0x00000000
Handle: 0x0003047A

Comment: AutoIt doesn't support MS UI Automation out of the box (Excel controls shouldn't be visible to AutoIt Spy tool or Spy++). You need `Inspect.exe` as a Spy tool. See "GUI Objects Inspection" in [pywinauto's Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html).

Comment: Am automating excel using win32ole and RAutomation gems here am trying achieve one functionality am using RAutomation adapter to find the element but am able to focus on that using win32adapter but not able to click on that and when I use msuia adapter target element cannot receive focus. here am attaching Auto It v3 Window Info
Window <<<< Title: Book1 - Excel, Class:XLMAIN,Position:-9, -9,Size:1938,1050, Style:0x17CF0000,ExStyle:0x00010110 Handle: 0x000908D4>>>> Control <<<>,Position:1656, 975,Size:248, 20,ControlClick Coords:30, 12,Style:0x56010000,ExStyle:0x00000000, Handle: 0x000C065C